# Ghost Blog Error 404 on Shared Hosting

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, ghost

I am trying to install Ghost on shared hosting by Godaddy.

I have managed to put NVM, Node, Ghost and the server configuration seems to be running. It is installed in a subdomain on my blog.

When I try to run the blog. there is a 404 error with `http://sub.domain.com/index.html.var/`in the URL.

I went on `http://sub.domain.com/Ghost/`. I was able to see the configuration page and was able to set up the blog but the blog is not showing up.

I do not know what am I missing. Any information you need I'll try to provide as much as I can.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am new to this, I didn't know the configurations of `.htaaccess` file.

I just added `DirectoryIndex` line before the rewriterule and the blog started working.

Hope this helps someone in future.